# Level order traversal in a binary search tree in java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, binaryfiles, tree-traversal

I have made 4 different traversals for my binary search tree. I am stuck at the last one which is the level order traversal and I can't get seem to find out how to do it correctly.

The main problem is that I don't know how to only search one level at a time, I only can figure out how to search either the whole left or whole right subtree.

```
private void preOrder(BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
        if(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Empty");
        }
        if(t != null) {
            System.out.println(t.element);
            preOrder(t.left);
            preOrder(t.right);
        }
    }

    private void postOrder(BinaryNode<AnyType> t){

        if(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Empty");
        }
        if (t != null) {
            postOrder(t.left);
            postOrder(t.right);
            System.out.println(t.element);
        }
    }

    private void inOrder(BinaryNode<AnyType> t)
    {
        if(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Empty");
        }

        if (t != null) {
            inOrder(t.left);
            System.out.println(t.element);
            inOrder(t.right);
        }
    }

    private void levelOrder(BinaryNode<AnyType> t, int level)
    {
        if(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Empty");
        }

        if(height(t) == 2) {
            System.out.println(t.element);

        }else if(height(t) > 1){
            levelOrder(t.left, level );
            levelOrder(t.right, level );
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please post [mcve]. Remove irrelevant code (like  other traversals) and add what is needed to run it. Also include test data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it.

```
private void levelOrder(BinaryNode root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }

        Queue<BinaryNode> q = new LinkedList<>();

        // Pushing root node into the queue.
        q.add(root);

        // Executing loop till queue becomes
        // empty
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {

            BinaryNode curr = q.poll();
            System.out.print(curr.element + " ");

            // Pushing left child current node
                if (curr.left != null) {
                    q.add(curr.left);
                }

                // Pushing right child current node
                if (curr.right != null) {
                    q.add(curr.right);
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks like DFS approach It may not follow that approach.
Try to use Queue here it will help you traverse correctly.
Because it will follow BFS approach so that you can traverse level by level.
Add first left node then right node and according follow.

Answer (score 0):

View the entire search as a sequence of "rounds", one "round" for each level.

In each round :

```
- initialize a "next round" list of nodes to empty
- process a prepared list of nodes (the ones that are at that level and thus to be searched in that round) whereby for each node :
  - do the actual comparison
  - add all the node's child nodes to the "next round" list
```

Start the process with a "next round" list populated with just the root node.

Repeat until the list of "next round" nodes comes up empty or you found what you were looking for.